# MongoError: user not allowed to create 2d index

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, node-mongodb-native, mongodb-indexes

I am creating a program to list nearby objects based on the user's current location.

For this I am using the old [longitude, latitude] system. I will store these coordinates in the `location` field.

The following error shows up when I try to create a `2d` index::

`MongoError: user is not allowed to do action [createIndex] on [data.system.indexes]`

However, I am dbAdmin hence I have all permission to create and drop indexes.

My code::

```
const uri = "mongodb:// <link with password and dbname>"
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;

function connect(){
    MongoClient.connect(uri, {useNewUrlParser: true}, (err, client)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
        else{
            const db = client.db(dbname);

            db.collection("collection").createIndex({"location": "2d"})
        }
    });
}
```

Also, please don't close this question as duplicate; in this case, the user is not the problem (since I am admin) and neither have I mixed up the password.

I can create `text` indexes just fine and am able to do stuff like dropping indexes and dropping the entire `db` so surely I can create the `2d` index?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of mongo are you using? @Jay John

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the error you're seeing with this code. The error suggests some part of your app is attempting to create an index on `system.indexes` instead of on `collection`. Does any part of your code attempt to access that collection?

Comment: Actually, all of the work is being done only on collection 'collection'. Does 2d index require other permissions? I am able to make text indexes just fine

Comment: @razki 3.2.2 - latest version

Comment: I was testing on MongoDB Atlas on a dev sandbox cluster when I got this error. Interestingly, I deleted all but one document (given that it was a test cluster) and I was able to create the index. No clue why.